# Android/iOS, abrir el browser con javascript desde un WebView

Tags: javascript, android, swift, objective-c, uiwebview

Hola quisiera alguna sugerencia, trato de abrir el navegador desde una página que se encuentra cargada desde un `WebView`/`UIWebView`, en una aplicación `iOS` o `Android` por ejemplo:

```
window.open(
  'http://www.stackoverflow',
  '_blank'.
);
```

Por seguridad en los nuevos OS esto puede ser un problema en cuanto a seguridad, pero quisiera una sugerencia de los expertos, ¿alguna posible solución?.

Alguna forma de abrir un url desde el `Webview`, no importando si requiero el uso de algún `Framework`, el uso de un `Intent` o interfaz queda descartado.

Comment: ¿Es para cordova/phonegap? Yo tengo un método en ese caso que podría compartir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo uso `cordova` para desarrollo en `android` y abro ventanas con este código:

```
navigator.app.loadUrl("URL_A_ABRIR", { openExternal:true });
```

Pero parece que ese método sólo funciona en Android y no en iOS. Para iOS existe un plugin de cordova llamado [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser) que funciona de manera similar aunque la notación es un poco diferente:

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('URL_A_ABRIR', { showLocationBar: true });
```

Pero de nuevo, esto es usando la plataforma de cordova. No sé cómo se integraría de manera nativa (el método de android debería funcionar, pero no estoy tan seguro sobre iOS).

Answer (score 4):

Te respondo para iOS nativo.

Trata tus enlaces en HTML como creas conveniente, abriendoles desde Javascript o con un hipervínculo:

```
<a href="http://mienlace.com">mi enlace</a>
```

Lo único que debes hacer con tu UIWebView es interceptar ese enlace en el delegado y lanzarlo en el navegador nativo.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
      return NO;

}
```